# How to use one function value in another function?

Tags: php, ajax, drupal-7

I have created a custom module in drupal 7.. using hook_menu() I am fetching a ajax value.I have created a call back function to get this value.. But I need to use this value in another function.

```
 $items['schoolfilterval/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'sfilterval',
    'page arguments'=> array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

function sfilterval($fvals){
 return $city_name;
}
```

I need to use $city_name in autocomplete functioan here:

```
function finderschool_autocomplete($string) {
  //here I need to use this $city_name value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can approach this you ca put the whole thing inside a class and do something like this:

```
Class MyClass {

protected $city_name;

    function sfilterval($fvals){
        $this->city_name;
    }

}
```

Or you could just call the function within the other function and get the value of `$city_name`. Something like this

```
function finderschool_autocomplete($string) {
   $newCity = function sfilterval($fvals);      
}
```

that will return $city_name and you can use it inside the function.

Hope that helps.